# Right way to handle error in getServerSideProps in Nextjs

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, next.js, use-effect

I am trying to handle any errors that come through getServerSideProps, which I check in via the if else condition, that works fine until I have any other hooks called like useEffect.
When I use the hook useEffect it gives the following error - which is though correct as per hook rules.

But it gives error  *Error: React Hook "useEffect" is called conditionally. React Hooks must be called in the exact same order in every component render*, when I use useEffect hook and do npm run build.

Can someone please help me, how to handle this

```
function Test({ data }) {
    console.log(data)

    if (data?.err) {
         return (<Error statusCode={data.err} />)
     }

 useEffect(() => {
   //fetch any data or do something

    return () => {
      
    };
  }, []);
  

return(<div>Return Div</>)

}

export default Test


export const getServerSideProps = async (context) => {


  const { data } = await axios.get(`${baseUrl}HomePage/all`).catch(err => {
    const dataerr = { data: { err: `${JSON.stringify(err?.response?.status)}` } }

    return dataerr
  })

  console.log(data)
  return { props: { data } }

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are using a conditional early return in `Test`. Move the `useEffect` (*and all other hooks*) hook above any function component returns so it is (*they are*) called ***unconditionally*** each render cycle.

```
function Test({ data }) {
  console.log(data);

  useEffect(() => {
    //fetch any data or do something

    return () => {
      
    };
  }, []);

  if (data?.err) {
    return <Error statusCode={data.err} />'
  }

  return <div>Return Div</>;
}
```